# Tailwindcss with react-native: why is my element not showing when set to flex grow?

Tags: css, react-native, tailwind-css

I am trying to create a simple options menu. I want the currently selected element to take all of the free space and the others just take like 40px. I condition my style to whether a certain element is currently selected, and if it is, then I set it to flex-grow instead of w-10, but then it simply doesn't render on the screen. Why is that?

```
<View className="flex flex-row mx-6 my-4 space-x-2 justify-between">
  <TouchableOpacity
    onPress={() => setCurrentAction("optionOne")}
    className={
      currentAction === "optionOne"
        ? "h-10 flex-grow rounded-md bg-blue-200"
        : "h-10 w-10 rounded-md bg-blue-200"
    }
  ></TouchableOpacity>
  <TouchableOpacity
    onPress={() => setCurrentAction("optionTwo")}
    className={
      currentAction === "optionTwo"
        ? "h-10 flex-grow rounded-md bg-red-200"
        : "h-10 w-10 rounded-md bg-red-200"
    }
  ></TouchableOpacity>
  <TouchableOpacity
    onPress={() => setCurrentAction("optionThree")}
    className={
      currentAction === "optionThree"
        ? "h-10 flex-grow rounded-md bg-green-200"
        : "h-10 w-10 rounded-md bg-green-200"
    }
  ></TouchableOpacity>
</View>
```

Comment: I'm not a tailwind expert, but are you sure flex-grow is the correct class? https://tailwindcss.com/docs/flex-grow

Comment: @Patrick I've been using flex-grow in many other places in my code and it's been working as expected. Interesting this part of the documentation says I should be using grow. Anyway, I've tried that as well and it doesn't work either.

Comment: Ah alright. To be honest neither Tailwind nor React-Native's my homecourt, I'm a React developer. I tried to translate your example to regular React, and it worked fine. Here's a sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/tailwind-css-and-react-forked-qb94nd?file=/src/App.js